# How to translate open graph objects

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I am quite new to facebook API. I have used the open graph to generate actions and objects.This actions are now validated by facebook. 
But, I have a translation trouble : the action and object are necessarily in english. And the facebook doc say that the action and objects are automatically translated when the meta tags are made 'locale', which was done. But my site is french and the actions an objects are still appearing in english. Does anyone can hep ?

(The ref's doc:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/internationalization/, http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/605/ )

Best ,
Newben

Answer (score 2):

If you’re already refering to the documentation – why don’t you *read* it as well?

The blog post says how translating your app works, and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/ describes it in more detail.

Comment: Excuse me but I read all this stuffs and I put the right meta tags like : <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />. Btw, I didn't find any link on the app dashbooard like "Translate Your App". And as it is suggested the link: https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/browse.php?app=<app_id> brings me back to my facebook personal page. Any idea ? Best, Newben

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps -> choose your app, edit it, the link „translate your app“ is right there in the list of links on the left side.

Comment: Right ! I was mislead by the doc that says that there was a link under the contact info area. Thanks a lot ! Best Newben.

Comment: @Lombo this page is said to be not reachable !

Comment: @Newben: There’s a new link “Localize” in the app dashboard now.

Comment: @Newben you need full admin rights (as an app developer it does not work)